# How can one create a reusable library structured as AMD module(s)?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

We are creating a framework that we intend to use across multiple projects.  All projects will use require.js to manage modules and dependencies.

Ideally I'd like to use the r.js optimizer to *compile the framework into a single file* that can be provided to the applications that use it.  That file will contain all modules of the framework such that in my application I can write code like:

```
define(["framework/util/a", "framework/views/b"], function(A, B) {
  var a = new A();
  // etc...
});
```

But it appears there are two problems with this approach.

1. Depending on `framework/util/a` doesn't tell require.js that it needs to load `framework.js` in which it will find `util/a`
2. The optimize tool generates names for all modules included in `framework.js` such as `define("util/a", function() { ... } );`  Even if require.js loaded `framework.js` there is nothing that tells it that the defined module `util/a` is a relative module to `framework` and as such is identified as `framework/util/a`

Am I missing something or is a better approach to structure my framework as a **CommonJS package** and use require.js's `packages` configuration option?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable way to do this.  From @jrburke: "just 'distribute modules in a directory in source form', no build."

Answer (score 2):

Re: 1. It seems that indeed r.js optimisation not was designed to optimise partial dependancy trees, as lazy loading hinges on file paths. E.g. asking `path/to/module` to actually load `path/to` would seem like a hack. One solution would be to forgo lazy loading and include `framework-built.js` above your application code.

Re: 2. So you'll now need your `framework-built.js` with full paths. One way would be to build a dummy parent that requires all of `framework`, say `dummy-framework.js`. That way your `dummy-framework-built.js` will have the full path defines for `framework` and if not lazy loaded, it should work fine.

Disclaimer: I haven't used require.js all that much, though that's my best effort :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  Your approach gets me the closest I've been able to get to what I wanted - definitely deserves the up-vote.  However, a quick conversation with jrburke tells me that I probably don't want to compile the library at all and instead just distribute the entire source folder.

Comment: I've chatted with James too, also learnt a bit more since when I posted this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302440/requirejs-is-there-a-way-to-achieve-multiple-base-urls where I answered my own question. So I achieve a 'framework' application by using custom `paths` for live lazy loading, and in production, locally, I build by pointing these same paths to local 'framework' which is just a sibling folder.